# Realm along with Android library project

Tags: java, android, realm

I have library project which contain some dependencies like fastadapter,nanotask, realm etc. I'm not able to get it worked along with main application. Somehow I need realm on library project and on main application too.

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

**Build error:**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
Multiple dex files define Lio/realm/DefaultRealmModule;
```

If I'm apply plugin only with library project than there is no more building error. But getting this error while using realm.

```
Task is not part of the schema for this Realm.
                     at io.realm.internal.RealmProxyMediator.getMissingProxyClassException(RealmProxyMediator.java:242)
                     at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.getTableName(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:107)
                     at io.realm.RealmSchema.getTable(RealmSchema.java:295)
                     at io.realm.Realm.checkHasPrimaryKey(Realm.java:1530)
                     at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Realm.java:952)
```

Here is library gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Realm is used in a library project, you must define a `RealmModule` with your schema. Otherwise, it will conflict with the schema being generated for the app. This is where the multiple `DefaultRealmModule` error comes from. You can read more about it here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sharing-schemas.

Specifically, it means that your RealmConfiguration in the library must look something like this:

```
@RealmModule(library = true, allClasses = true)
public class MyLibraryModule() {

}

RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .modules(new MyLibraryModule())
  .build();
```

Comment: How do I import Realm into the library only, without a Realm in the app, since there is no project level gradle file in the library?

Comment: Hi, where would one set the RealmConfiguration in the library? is everywhere ok or is there a specific place to set it? Or should i set it inside the Application instead of the library module?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem that @ono and alessandro are facing.

Comment: @alessandrogaboardi did you find any solution?

Comment: Sorry but i actually abandoned the project, and Realm altoghether, now i use Room